# Parsing JSON array into class instance objects?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse some data in Python I have some JSON:

```
{
    "data sources": [
        "http://www.gcmap.com/"
    ],
    "metros": [
        {
            "code": "SCL",
            "continent": "South America",
            "coordinates": {
                "S": 33,
                "W": 71
            },
            "country": "CL",
            "name": "Santiago",
            "population": 6000000,
            "region": 1,
            "timezone": -4
        },
        {
            "code": "LIM",
            "continent": "South America",
            "coordinates": {
                "S": 12,
                "W": 77
            },
            "country": "PE",
            "name": "Lima",
            "population": 9050000,
            "region": 1,
            "timezone": -5
        }
    ]
}
```

If I wanted to parse the `"metros"` array into and array of Python class `Metro` objects, how would I setup the class?

I was thinking:

```
class Metro(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.code = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.country = ""
        self.continent = ""
        self.timezone = ""
        self.coordinates = []
        self.population = 0
        self.region = ""
```

So I want to go through each metro and put the data into a corresponding `Metro` object and place that object into a Python array of objects...How can I loop through the JSON metros?

Comment: I do not understand the question. When you have JSON you have an object and you can get the metros list from this object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you always get the same keys, you can use `**` to easily construct your instances. Making the `Metro` a `namedtuple` will simplify your life if you are using it simply to hold values:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Metro = namedtuple('Metro', 'code, name, country, continent, timezone, coordinates,
                   population, region')
```

then simply

```
import json
data = json.loads('''...''')
metros = [Metro(**k) for k in data["metros"]]
```

Comment: this gives me an error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: metros = [Metro(**k) for k in data["metros"]] for that line

Comment: ...did you get `data` from `json.loads`? Because if `data` is your raw JSON data then of course this won't work.

Comment: i used metros = json.dumps[myData["metros"]] then
myMetros = [Metro(**k) for k in metros["metros"]]

Comment: ...??? `dumps` gives you a string...if you already have `myData["metros"]` then why are you mucking with `json` in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming, you are using json to load the data, I would use a list of namedtuple here to store the data under the key 'metro'

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> metros = []
>>> for e in data[u'metros']:
    metros.append(namedtuple('metro', e.keys())(*e.values()))


>>> metros
[metro(code=u'SCL', name=u'Santiago', country=u'CL', region=1, coordinates={u'S': 33, u'W': 71}, timezone=-4, continent=u'South America', population=6000000), metro(code=u'LIM', name=u'Lima', country=u'PE', region=1, coordinates={u'S': 12, u'W': 77}, timezone=-5, continent=u'South America', population=9050000)]
>>>
```

Comment: I would create the `namedtuple` in advance. `namedtuple` does an `eval` on a class definition, so it is quite heavyweight.

Answer (score 5):

It's relatively easy to do since you've read the data with `json.load()` which will return a Python dictionary for each element in "metros" in this case — just walk though it and create the list of`Metro`class instances. I modified the calling sequence of the `Metro.__init__()` method you had to make it easier to pass data to it from the dictionary returned from `json.load()`.

Since each element of the "metros" list in the result is a dictionary, you can just pass that to class `Metro`'s constructor using `**` notation to turn it into keyword arguments. The constructor can then just `update()` it's own `__dict__` to transfer those values to itself.

By doing things this way, instead of using something like a `collections.namedtuple` as just a data container, is that `Metro` is a custom class which makes adding other methods and/or attributes you wish to it trivial.

```
import json

class Metro(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        fields = ['    {}={!r}'.format(k,v)
                    for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')]

        return '{}(\n{})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ',\n'.join(fields))


with open('metros.json') as file:
    json_obj = json.load(file)

metros = [Metro(**metro_dict) for metro_dict in json_obj['metros']]

for metro in metros:
    print('{}\n'.format(metro))
```

Output:

```
Metro(
    code='SCL',
    continent='South America',
    coordinates={'S': 33, 'W': 71},
    country='CL',
    name='Santiago',
    population=6000000,
    region=1,
    timezone=-4)

Metro(
    code='LIM',
    continent='South America',
    coordinates={'S': 12, 'W': 77},
    country='PE',
    name='Lima',
    population=9050000,
    region=1,
    timezone=-5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the json module from the library http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html to convert the json to a Python dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
import json
data = json.loads(<json string>)
data.metros = [Metro(**m) for m in data.metros]

class Metro(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.code = kwargs.get('code', 0)
        self.name = kwargs.get('name', "")
        self.county = kwargs.get('county', "")
        self.continent = kwargs.get('continent', "")
        self.timezone = kwargs.get('timezone', "")
        self.coordinates = kwargs.get('coordinates', [])
        self.population = kwargs.get('population', 0)
        self.region = kwargs.get('region', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [17]: def load_flat(data, inst):
   ....:     for key, value in data.items():
   ....:         if not hasattr(inst, key):
   ....:             raise AttributeError(key)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             setattr(inst, key, value)
   ....:             

In [18]: m = Metro()

In [19]: load_float(data['metros'][0], m)

In [20]: m.__dict__
Out[20]: 
{'code': 'SCL',
 'continent': 'South America',
 'coordinates': {'S': 33, 'W': 71},
 'country': 'CL',
 'name': 'Santiago',
 'population': 6000000,
 'region': 1,
 'timezone': -4}
```

Not only is it very much readable and very explicit about what it does, but it also provides some basic field validation as well (raising exceptions on mismatched fields, etc)

Answer (score -1):

I would try [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html). Something like:

```
metro = Metro()
metro.__dict__ = ast.literal_eval(a_single_metro_dict_string)
```

Comment: True, but from what I see in OP's question, this will suffice.

Comment: Yeah...but if the question says "json" I would stick with a JSON parser.

Comment: And if "right" was a comparative adjective, I would say your answer is "righter"